# CKEditor Image Upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ckeditor, wysiwyg, image-uploading

I am looking to include [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com) in a project I am working on and I need the image upload support provided by the [CKFinder](http://ckfinder.com/) plugin, however I do not particularly need the rest of the CKFinder tool and thus purchasing a license is a little overkill. Has anyone taken the time to implement a custom image uploader for CKEditor 3 that will work with ASP.NET MVC? If need be I can create my own, just wanted to check here first.

Alternatively, does anyone know of a decent WYSIWYG editor on par with [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com) / [Cute Editor](http://cutesoft.net/ASP.NET+WYSIWYG+Editor/) that supports image uploading and will work in ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here is a image uploader I originally wrote in ASP.NET WebForms for Fckeditor (hence the theme no longer matches), that I've modified to work with Ckeditor.

https://github.com/mcm-ham/ckeditor-image-uploader

Update: I've now added an example showing how you can add this WebForms image uploader to a MVC project.

Update 2: I've now added a Razor Pages version which can be used in .NET Core MVC projects.

Comment: Excellent this saved me a lot of problems!

Comment: This example is webforms rather than MVC.

Comment: This image loader is webforms based but should still work in a MVC project. How Ckeditor is added to the page can be ignored. Just ImageBrowser.aspx, LinkBrowser.aspx & config.js under the ckeditor folder need to be copied over as well as the two appSettings in web.config.

Comment: @Michael When i include the dll i get this error `Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.  The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)`. This is an website targeting .net framework 4.0. Do you know how to resolve this? Thanks for image up-loader.

Comment: @Answer fixed, I did do a custom build of the library because of [this issue](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1126) I was experiencing but decided it's easier to just go back to what I had and remove dependency on that library.

Comment: Great job Michael, your example made my day~! After 4 hours searching, I found your example and it works! Only one question, how to save the content of the editor to storage in MVC 5? Thanks~!

Comment: Check this URL http://r2d2.cc/2010/11/03/file-and-image-upload-with-asp-net-mvc2-with-ckeditor-wysiwyg-rich-text-editor/

Comment: The URL in the answer is broken :(

Comment: @Seth, I've just updated the URL hopefully you won't be asked for credentials.

Comment: Hi, I acted according to your code, but when I click the OK button, the image is not displayed in `textarea`. How do I solve this problem?@Michael

Answer (score 22):

Here is a tutorial on how to upload image with ASP:NET MVC2 (not Webforms) using CKEditor

http://arturito.net/2010/11/03/file-and-image-upload-with-asp-net-mvc2-with-ckeditor-wysiwyg-rich-text-editor/

Comment: This example is MVC.  The only problem is that it's incomplete (the controller doesn't actually save the file).  But, you can fix that in section "6. Controller..." if you replace line 6-10 (and fix line 13 and 16) with the logic Phil talks about in http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx

Comment: Finally, after looking into a lot of plugins..! Thanks!

Comment: I have created an updated version of Arturito solution that includes actual file upload too: https://gist.github.com/afsharm/5660844

Answer (score 2):

I have used ckeditor and the upload control using ASP.NET, but not MVC specifically.  I haven't found anything on par with ckeditor that is even close to being as easy to set up or offers the same features.

Not sure of the restrictions for MVC, but I set up file upload support by using the following:

- The basic documentation referring mostly to the CKFinder plugin you mentioned:

http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/File_Browser_%28Uploader%29

- Better documentation on how to implement the upload component:

[How can you integrate a custom file browser/uploader with CKEditor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498628/how-can-you-integrate-a-custom-file-browser-uploader-with-ckeditor)

Otherwise, I believe ckeditor just stuffs all the image bytes in the request object and sends it to the page configured for uploading.  This page can take those bytes and do whatever it pleases (i.e. save them to the file system, sql server, etc.)   This is where the custom implementation comes in.

Instead of using a page to do the upload, I used an httphandler implementation.  The page ckeditor redirects to calls the requisite javascript function to indicate the status of the upload after it is complete, but the handler really controls the actual file upload.  The basic implementation for the httphandler I used is at:

http://darrenjohnstone.net/2008/07/15/aspnet-file-upload-module-version-2-beta-1/

Hope this at least gives you a starting point.

---

UPDATE: found this while searching for some other stuff.  Didn't look at in depth, but seems to be right up your alley:

http://interactiveasp.net/blogs/spgilmore/archive/2009/06/03/how-to-support-file-uploads-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you need to implement it quickly and have a reliable solution, you may consider a hosted solution to upload and store images for CKEditor - for example, our plugin:

http://ckeditor.com/addon/uploadcare