# Enable image upload for CKEditor at asp.net

Tags: asp.net, image, upload, ckeditor

i use CKEditor for my asp.net C# project.
How can I enable image upload tab for the editor. I read find some articles but none of them where useful. some of them where for php. I want for asp.net.
thank you for helping.

Comment: Answered already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115302/ckeditor-image-upload-filebrowseruploadurl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I could find the solution.

I did two things to solve my problem.

first I edited config.ascx file and set the base url to images folder. like below:

public override void SetConfig()
    {

```
    // The base URL used to reach files in CKFinder through the browser.
    BaseUrl = "~/images/";
    // The phisical directory in the server where the file will end up. If
    // blank, CKFinder attempts to resolve BaseUrl.
    BaseDir = "";
}
```

and the mistake that I had was that, my pages was at admin folder and I was put ckeditor and ckfinder folder at root of my website.

by puting these files at the admin folder the problem soved.

thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I do like the http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/423_Upload_Images_and_Integrate_with_CKeditor_in_AspNet.aspx letutorial for Using filebrowserImageUploadUrl property with our own implementation of a file uploader. but the botton of upload didn't appear and nothing happened. my code is here:

```
<head runat="server">

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            CKEDITOR.replace('<%=CKEditor1.ClientID %>', { filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/Upload.ashx' });
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditor1" BasePath="~/ckeditor/" runat="server" Width="600px" Height="200px"></CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the ashx file:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Upload" %>

using System;
using System.Web;

public class Upload : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        HttpPostedFile uploads = context.Request.Files["upload"];
        string CKEditorFuncNum = context.Request["CKEditorFuncNum"];
        string file = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uploads.FileName);
        uploads.SaveAs(context.Server.MapPath(".") + "\\Images\\" + file);
        string url = "/Images/" + file;
        context.Response.Write("<script>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(" + CKEditorFuncNum + ", \"" + url + "\");</script>");
        context.Response.End();            
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to enable the hidden tab the add only under script folder

```
CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins = 'imageuploader';
```

But there will be a error in console, because you have to define the link, which will be action to upload the file/image, like

```
filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: 'YourController/YourAction',            
filebrowserImageUploadUrl: 'YourController/YourAction'
```