# How to return CKEditorFuncNum?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

`$funcNum = $_GET['CKEditorFuncNum'] ;` is not returning the number.

I tried creating the upload.php for ckeditor uploadimage plugin according to 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44553006/8719001 (sorry can't add comments yet)

which includes `echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction($funcNum, '$url', '$message');</script>";`

However when I drop images it doesn't work and in the console I get the Response Text which doesn't show any funcNumber:

```
"<script type='text/javascript'>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(, 'https://example.com/upload/test.jpg', '');</script>"
```

I think this might be part of filebrowser plugin? 
Which I have enabled and also declared `$settings['filebrowserUploadUrl'] =`

Answer (score 9):

Try to setup config.js insert `config.filebrowserUploadMethod = 'form';`,if you got CKEditor additional arguments empty,(CKEditor,langCode,CKEditorFuncNum). There are some errors occur,
 `Incorrect server response.` and `[CKEDITOR] Error code: filetools-response-error.`.
please refer,https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/issues/1894

Answer (score 2):

This is the version problem.
I tried 2 hours and couldn't get the parameter CKEditorFuncNum with java like you.
After I changed my 4.9.1 version to 4.7.3, it worked.