# Help setting up image upload in CK Editor, using jquery config

Tags: jquery, image, ckeditor, file-upload

I have been trying to set up CKeditor with Perch CMS which requires using jQuery adapter option for initialising the CK Editor.

Below is what I have as my configuration options for CK editor and my upload folder is "resources" which is located in my root folder e.g. domain.com/resources

Although the upload tab appears under the image button/page when I try to submit an image I get a "Not Found" error.

What am I missing?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    var config = {
        toolbar: [
            ['Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Link', 'Unlink'],
            ['Image','Maximize'],
            ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock']
        ],
        filebrowserUploadUrl : '/resources/'
    };

    $('textarea.ckeditor').ckeditor(config);
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

`fileBrowserUploadUrl` is meant to point to an upload script than handles the upload rather than the folder that the uploads will appear in.

There are some good pointers on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498628/how-can-you-integrate-a-custom-file-browser-uploader-with-ckeditor) and [zerokspot's blog](http://zerokspot.com/weblog/2009/09/09/custom-filebrowser-callbacks-ckeditor/).