# Java/JSP Web File Manager like CKFinder or KCFinder

Tags: java, jsp, open-source, file-management

I like [CKFinder](http://ckfinder.com/), but it is a commercial product. 
I also like [KCFinder](http://kcfinder.sunhater.com/), but it works on PHP only, I need it to run on Java/JSP.

Know any open source Java/JSP web file manager?

Edit:

The next best thing I found is this, http://www.vonloesch.de/filebrowser.html but it is quite old and basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround..

First install the old FCKEditor Java, -> http://sourceforge.net/projects/fckeditor/files/

Then use the following instruction to integrate it with CKEditor. http://docs.gpeasy.org/index.php/Main/CKEditor_Integration

Check out this too:

[How can you integrate a custom file browser/uploader with CKEditor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498628/how-can-you-integrate-a-custom-file-browser-uploader-with-ckeditor)