# file browser/uploader with CKEditor?

Tags: php, javascript

[How can you integrate a custom file browser/uploader with CKEditor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498628/how-can-you-integrate-a-custom-file-browser-uploader-with-ckeditor)

after read the answer, i still don't know which file in ckeditor package should  put the code in ? expect someone can explian it. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the config file.. config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = 'FileBrowser/'; point it to the finder thing

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ){
config.forcePasteAsPlainText = true;
config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_P;
config.shiftEnterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
**config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = 'FileBrowser/';**
config.filebrowserWindowWidth = '950';
config.filebrowserWindowHeight = '480';
config.templates_files = [
    'ckeditor/templates/site.js',
];
config.language = "en";
```

};

just put the path of the file browser in.. ckfinder etc