# ckeditor z-index on textarea resize

Tags: ckeditor, z-index

I am using ckeditor in a page with a 2 columns layout.
The left column has a form with a ckeditor in it, and the right column has an image and some content.

It's possible to resize the ckeditor textarea by dragging the bottom right corner, but the ckeditor window goes "under" the image/content in the right column.

It's like the z-index of the ckeditor is inferior to the image/content in the other column, and I would like to change this behavior so the ckeditor goes "above" the image.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try putting the CKEditor in a div which has z-index higher than the right column div(or whatever). I can think about this simplest solution right away without testing it.

Answer (score 5):

Old post but hopefully someone will find this helpfull.
Add this to your config.js : config.baseFloatZIndex = 100001