# Is there any PHP Plug in for uploading an image in ckeditor?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to upload an image in ckeditor without using their inbuilt image upload.

Please suggest me if there is any other plugin in php for uploading an image which supports CK editor.

Comment: Hmmm, seems to be only small custom ones, else see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498628/how-can-you-integrate-a-custom-file-browser-uploader-with-ckeditor

Answer (score 0):

from the makers of CKEditor comes CKFinder:  http://ckfinder.com/

It is very compatible, but not as free:  $59.