# CKEditor external file browser

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, file-browser

I'm trying to return file url from external file browser to CKEditor but I'm receiving error which is:

```
[09:02:18.038] TypeError: A._.filebrowserSe is undefined @ http://www.xxx.pl/yyy/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js:56
```

I'm using this code:

```
window.parent.opener.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(number,url);
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer: [How can you integrate a custom file browser/uploader with CKEditor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498628/how-can-you-integrate-a-custom-file-browser-uploader-with-ckeditor)

You should to receive GET parameter called CKEditorFuncNum.

I use it such way in php:

```
window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(<?=intval($_REQUEST['CKEditorFuncNum'])?>, url, message);
```