# How can I customize the design of CKEditor image upload dialog?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor

I could set up custom image upload in CKEditor. Thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1498674/601148)

Now my issue is, I want to change the default image upload dialogue. I need a simple upload dialogue, which should only have the file browser and a textbox to paste the link.

I couldn't find the `HTML` file for this dialogue. I think it is creating from a `JS` file which is in the `image` plugin. Is there anyway, I can customize this window and get the desired look ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the asnwer to this into the **[CKEditor's Dialog API documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.dialog.html)**