# CKEditor - Using ImageBrowse plugin not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ckeditor

I am trying to use ImageBrowser plugin (http://devture.com/projects/ckeditor-imagebrowser) with CK Editor.

As required i have configured:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor',                     
                      {
                        "extraPlugins" : 'imagebrowser',
                        "imageBrowser_listUrl" : "/getimagelist/images_list.js"
                      } );
```

The Image Browse window shows up correctly with images, but when i select an image i get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setCustomData' of undefined.
```

If it matters my CKEditor is in AngularJS application.

Alternatively: Any other ideas or plugins i can use?