# What is the minimum requirement to upload an image in CKeditor?

Tags: javascript, image, ckeditor, uploading, ckeditor4.x

I use jQuery adapter in my program. I tried a number of configurations, but the upload button does not appear on the image dialog.

Which files should be included in the page and how it should be configured? 
Please provide a minimum working example of an Ckeditor that can simply upload an image to server.

Answer (score 3):

Minimum Requirements:

> You should use [uploadimage](http://ckeditor.com/addon/uploadimage)
>   addon in CKeditor for [uploading image in
>   CKeditor](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/fileupload.html#uploading-dropped-and-pasted-images)

Once properly set up through the `config.filebrowserBrowseUrl` and `config.filebrowserUploadUrl` configuration settings, all file manager features will automatically become available. This includes the Upload tab in the Link or Image Properties dialog windows as well as the Browse Server button.

Some steps:

1. Make sure your CKEditor instance includes an “Insert Image” button
2. Enable the file upload dialogue box
3. Telling CKEditor where your image upload script lives
4. Writing the script to handle the image upload in Backend
5. Grant Correct File Permissions to your Backend Script

More resources:

1. http://www.mixedwaves.com/2010/02/integrating-fckeditor-filemanager-in-ckeditor/
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1498674/1045444