# CKEditor upload; PHP $_FILES array empty after submitting file

Tags: upload, ckeditor

CKEditor's "upload" tab will submit a file in the field "upload" - in PHP, that goes to $_FILES['upload']

The sentence above is taken from: [How can you integrate a custom file browser/uploader with CKEditor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498628/how-can-you-integrate-a-custom-file-browser-uploader-with-ckeditor)

My problem: after selecting a file from my local Windows hard drive and hitting the "Send to server" button, the file is not accessible in $_FILES['upload'], more specifically, the $_FILES array is empty.

Does anyone have an idea what I might be doing wrong? Thanks for your support.

Comment: Please provide plugin code

Comment: As @SAZ mentioned, could you share your code: CKEditor config and php server side code? What CKEditor are you using to upload files?

Comment: I'm sorry for taking so much time to respond: managed to solve the problem myself...thanks for your support.

Comment: @DurianNangka please let update answer or put comment. I have same issue and not able to resolve it.